# Bootstrap Modal at Bottom Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

For my last project I use **Material Design** for the website right now I **switch** to **Bootstrap**. Right now I'm looking for a way on how to create the bootstrap modal display actions to the user on the bottom of a screen. They still act the same as regular modals. I am looking for a modal that act like the [Bottom Sheet Modal](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) of materializecss. **Is  this possible for a bootstrap to do it? Or there are existing way to do it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is, but you need to change the modal css a little bit:

Note: the only change you need to do is adding style to the element `class="modal-dialog"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" >
      <div class="modal-dialog" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;margin:0;width:100%;">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Example from: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: Okay thanks. I only need now is making this full width.

Comment: already eddited my code to the full width (: just needed add width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 5, you can use [Offcanvas components](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/offcanvas/#placement). It's just like  Bottom Sheet Modal in materializecss.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasBottom" aria-controls="offcanvasBottom">Toggle bottom offcanvas</button>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-bottom" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasBottom" aria-labelledby="offcanvasBottomLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-header">
    <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasBottomLabel">Offcanvas bottom</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="offcanvas-body small">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```